# Split columntext to rows (extract delimiter in bracket) ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle, split, rows, delimiter

I have a Column in a Database which contains multiple Values in one Column, which i need as different rows.
The Column contains comma delimited parts but also a Part with comma in brackets. I don't need to split this parts. (Only split on commas which are NOT in brackets)

## Versions

Oracle 11g

## Example:

```
**ID | Kategory**

1 | "ATD 5(2830),ATO 4(510),EDI 1,EH A1,SCI 2,SS 1,STO-SE 1(oral, CNS, blood),STO-SE 2(oral, respiratory effects)"
```

This string i need as

```
 - 1 => ATD 5(2830)
 - 1 => ATO 4(510)
 - 1 => EDI 1
 - 1 => EH A1
 - 1 => SCI 2
 - 1 => SS 1
 - 1 => STO-SE 1(oral,CNS, blood)
 - 1 => STO-SE 2(oral, respiratory effects)
```

Parts like (oral, CNS, blood) which contains comma in brackets i don't need to split.

Comment: Can we rely on  ","  which is not followed by a space, as delimiter? Since all your commas inside () have spaces following and delimiter does not

Comment: Hi Kaushik Nayak, Nope this is not trusted. Because the Data is coming from External Comapny, where we can not now, if this every time in same format. (Comma will stay specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `(([^(]*?(\(.*?\))?)*)(,|$)` to match:

- `[^(]*?` Zero-or-more (but as few as possible) non-opening-bracket characters
- `(\(.*?\))?` Then, optionally, an opening bracket and as few characters as possible until the closing bracket.
- `(                )*` Wrapped in a capturing group repeated zero-or-more times
- `(                   )` Wrapped in a capturing group to be able to reference the entire matched item
- `(,|$)` Followed by either a comma or the end-of-string.

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e6e80/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Kategory ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ATD 5(2830),ATO 4(510),EDI 1,EH A1,SCI 2,SS 1,STO-SE 1(oral, CNS, blood),STO-SE 2(oral, respiratory effects)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID,
       l.COLUMN_VALUE AS item,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         Kategory,
         '(([^(]*?(\(.*?\))?)*)(,|$)',
         1,
         l.COLUMN_VALUE,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( t.Kategory, '(([^(]*?(\(.*?\))?)*)(,|$)' )
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) l
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e6e80/1/0)**:

```
| ID | ITEM |                               VALUE |
|----|------|-------------------------------------|
|  1 |    1 |                         ATD 5(2830) |
|  1 |    2 |                          ATO 4(510) |
|  1 |    3 |                               EDI 1 |
|  1 |    4 |                               EH A1 |
|  1 |    5 |                               SCI 2 |
|  1 |    6 |                                SS 1 |
|  1 |    7 |          STO-SE 1(oral, CNS, blood) |
|  1 |    8 | STO-SE 2(oral, respiratory effects) |
```