# SQL / How to get multiple records based on a semicolon char in a particular column

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle12c, substr

I'm wondering how to solve this without using any functions. I've got some kind of embedded SQL Client (12c) in the application where I'm working on and therefore I cannot use functions & procedures outside of the query.

I'm having this input:

`ID ¦ APP
14 ¦ AAA;BBBB;CC
15 ¦ AAA;DDDDD
16 ¦ BBBB;CC
17 ¦ AAA;BBBB;CC;DDDDD`

I would like dynamically transform into this:

`ID ¦ APP
14 ¦ AAA
14 ¦ BBBB
14 ¦ CC
15 ¦ AAA
15 ¦ DDDDD
16 ¦ BBBB
16 ¦ CC
17 ¦ AAA
17 ¦ BBBB
17 ¦ CC
17 ¦ DDDDD`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to find: [how to split string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+split+string+comma)

Comment: you may consider this ( by replacing `,` with `;` ) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376315/split-columntext-to-rows-extract-delimiter-in-bracket-oracle-sql

Comment: One of many duplicates of [How to convert comma separated values to rows in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle). This must have been asked at least once a day since the mid-90s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, app) as
  2  (select 14, 'aaa;bbb;cc' from dual union
  3   select 15, 'aaa;dddd'   from dual union
  4   select 16, 'bbbb;cc'    from dual
  5  )
  6  select id, regexp_substr(app, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) app
  7  from test,
  8       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                           connect by level <= regexp_count(app, ';') + 1)
 10                           as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by 1, 2;

        ID APP
---------- ----------------------------------------
        14 aaa
        14 bbb
        14 cc
        15 aaa
        15 dddd
        16 bbbb
        16 cc

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Littlefoot's answer was accepted as the answer, but I enjoy playing with common table expressions so I developed a solution using CTE. This solution can be used on non-Oracle platforms:

```
WITH
    test_dataset (id, app)
    AS
        (SELECT 14 AS id, 'aaa;bbb;cc' AS app
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 15, 'aaa;dddd'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 16, 'bbbb;cc'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 17, 'ZZZZ'
           FROM DUAL),
    aset (id, app, extra)
    AS
        (SELECT id
              , CASE WHEN INSTR (app, ';') = 0 THEN app ELSE SUBSTR (app, 1, INSTR (app, ';') - 1) END AS app
              , CASE WHEN INSTR (app, ';') = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR (app, INSTR (app, ';') + 1) END AS extra
           FROM test_dataset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id
              , CASE WHEN INSTR (extra, ';') = 0 THEN extra ELSE SUBSTR (extra, 1, INSTR (extra, ';') - 1) END
              , CASE WHEN INSTR (extra, ';') = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTR (extra, INSTR (extra, ';') + 1) END
           FROM aset
          WHERE extra IS NOT NULL)
  SELECT id, app
    FROM aset
ORDER BY id, app;
```

The answer?

```
ID APP
14 aaa
14 bbb
14 cc
15 aaa
15 dddd
16 bbbb
16 cc
17 ZZZZ
```